# Updating a table, on a button press, with selected information

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to update a database table when someone applies for a job within an apex  mobile application.

The current set up is a SelectList with the job titles and an apply button below that. I'd like the end user to be able to select a job and hit the apply. Doing so would then update another table with the required information.

How would I go about getting the button to update the database with the information from the SelectList?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd create a **process** which fires when a button is pressed. Process is, normally, a PL/SQL block which can either directly do the update, or call a stored procedure which will do that job.

**[EDIT: some more info]**

Select list item has two values: display and return. You see the *display* value, but in session state is stored its *return value* - you'll work with the later. How? Pass it to your procedure. For example, process might look like this:

```
update your_table set
  job = :P1_SELECT_LIST_JOB_ID
  where id = :P1_SOMEONES_ID;
```

If it is a procedure, then

```
begin
  p_your_procedure(:P1_SOMEONES_ID, :P1_SELECT_LIST_JOB_ID);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've managed to get the button click updating the table, However, I still don't know how I would make it so the PL/SQL uses the information from the drop down to update the table?

Comment: You're welcome. I've added some more info into my answer; have a look.